# animation "forwards" doesn't keep the last state

Tags: css, css-animations

I have this code:

```js
function startAnimation() {
  $(".block").addClass("removed");
}
```

```css
.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  background-color: #000;
  position: relative;
}
.block:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 10px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 10px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 20px);
}
.block.removed:after {
  animation: lock_removed 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes lock_removed {
  5% {
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 11px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 11px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 20px);
  }
  10% {
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 12px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 12px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 20px);
  }
  15% {
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 13px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 13px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 20px);
  }
  20% {
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 14px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 14px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 20px);
  }
  25% {
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 15px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 15px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 20px);
  }
  30% {
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 16px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 16px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 20px);
  }
  35% {
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 17px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 17px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 20px);
  }
  40% {
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 18px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 18px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 20px);
  }
  45% {
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 19px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 19px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 20px);
  }
  50% {
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 20px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 20px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 20px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block"></div>
<input type="button" value="Start Animation" onClick="startAnimation()"/>
```

Thing is, after clicking the button, the animation runs but doesn't stop at 100%, but reverts back to the previous state (with crossing lines) although I use forwards in the animation-fill-mode...

Any idea on why it behaves like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your animation hasn't 100% finished.

Change your last line to:

```
100% {
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 20px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 20px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 20px);
}
```

Comment: Ahhh silly me, didn't notice my animation wasn't complete (I create it using scss and I made a mistake in the loop).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem, easy mistake to make. Can you accept the answer please.

Comment: Accepted now, for some reason I had to wait for 2 minutes...

Thanks again!